# Is JNI a solution to increase bit manipulation performance?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, bit-manipulation

I have a java class that does really heavy bit decoding and manipulation. This class accounts to almost 96% of my total app's execution time. I was wondering whether if I write some c code for these bit manipulation and use java native methods to load the c libraries, will I get significant increase in my performance?

Comment: Possibly. It's precisely the kind of code that most JVM's can handle very well though. If there were objects, arrays or trig involved, that would be something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could see JNI/native code being faster is you can overcome the JNI call overhead by passing a large dataset to the native method for it to bit manipulate.  Note that unlike Java methods, JNI methods cannot be inlined/optimized by hotspot. Native calls require copying values back and forth between the Java and Native memory areas.

Answer (score 3):

The only real way to find out is to do careful benchmarking using a purpose-built Java benchmarking tool -- [Caliper](http://caliper.googlecode.com) comes to mind -- but I personally doubt that you'd win enough performance to outweigh the JNI overhead.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Louis, the best way to know is to measure. The overhead of calling through JNI is significant. The better question to ask is if you are calling your methods frequently. In other words, to consume 96% of the execution time, does your bit manipulation method get called thousands of times per second or does it do significant work in a single call? If it's the latter, then it's highly likely that you will benefit from native code.